# How to send custom notifications in KDE ? 

Tags: kde, notify-osd

As we all know that Ubuntu release its event updates with notifications and of course Kubuntu also does the same job but with different style .

but is there any way to get Kubuntu notifications in Ubuntu.

EDIT: Ok here `knotify4` will do the job but how can i send custom notification alerts from that ?

Comment: KDE uses `knotify` for it's notification events, you would have to Install that, there is no `knotify` package however but there is a library which will Install, of course you will have to install several KDE dependencies.

Comment: From what would you be sending your "custom notification alerts"?

Comment: just for testing , something like we did in Ubuntu with unity DE with notify-send . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "notify-send" in KDE too. Such as this

```
notify-send "custom kde notification"
```

It works in default KDE setup. I think, KDE notification also uses "notify-send"'s library.

From a  later comment by OP, I understand the requirement of placing the notification at the top-right position of the screen like Unity's notify-osd. It's very simple to achieve.

First send a custom notification using `notify-send "custom notification"` and then drag the notification window to your desired location. From this moment, your notification will now be appear on your desired location.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand clearly. Do you want to use knotify in Ubuntu?

Comment: I would like to have them on Top right as we get in Ubuntu .

Comment: OK, I get them on top-right on my KDE. but .... I really don't know how it got there. will update soon.

Comment: @August I've found it. updated the answer. See whether it is what you wanted

Comment: Thanks Anwar , thats how i want it . may i configure it like hiding when i placed mouse over there on notification ?

Comment: @August I'll try to find that too. But I still don't know about it.