# How can I receive a visual notification each time a process has finished in a terminal window?

Tags: command-line, notify-osd

I would like to **always** receive a visual notification when a process has finished in a terminal window. Example of such a process:

```
youtube-dl -cit --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/....
```

Comment: Would something like this work for you?
`sleep 30 ; xmessage -center "Sleep 30 Done"`
Where you substitute `sleep 30` with your command and enter the text you like between the double quotes?  Basically, it's two commands executed in sequence.  That's what the `; `stands for: it separates two commands.

Comment: Thank you! I would prefer [this type](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4jCOMhNcBmW1MCYyPhH2O5ime5npPB4bHpB8gPpKEfCbpn17b) of notification, however.

Comment: Probably doable with some DBus magic...  Let's see if Google yields anything...

Comment: What process? A specific one that you've started? *Any* process running on the system? Any process started by your user? Also, should the notification depend on whether the process finished successfully or failed or was stopped? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Didn't you ask a related question some months ago? That time it was about making a notification like the one some other OS (Elementary) provided and you were pointed to `alert` in Ubuntu's .bashrc.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the reminder @DKBose! But this time I don't want this to happen manually by using `alert` but make this the default feature.

Comment: shortest way I know is alias in .bashrc `alias a='notify-send "Completed"` execution `youtube-dl ;a`

Comment: Can this be set-up so that I don't even have to type the alias `a` before a command?

Comment: I think that with [undistract-me](http://askubuntu.com/a/617735/403828) I found the perfect solution for my scenario!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
yourlongrunningcommand ; notify-send "Yay! We're done!  Off to the bar!"
```

To understand the command:

- The `;` denoted sequential execution.  First execute `yourlongrunningcommand` and when done, execute the next command... which is
- `notify-send`, which is nothing more than the type of notification
  you wanted as per our comment exchange

I just googled to know that second part.   I found this on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225580/need-to-cause-a-notification-in-12-04-from-shell).